# How to get MAX() value and Record Primary Key where the value occurs in a Database?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access-2007

I have a database with `Hours` as `integer` field and `PK` like `record ID`/`Autonumber` in a table to identify records. How can I with an SQL Query get the value max value and the record ID or field value where the max value is located? **I am using a `.mdb MS Access` database.**

Code I am currently using:

```
        with dmpat.ADOQuery1 do
        begin
          sql.Clear; //Hours is integer field
          //Here I would like to get the ID (integer) field value of each of these values:
          sql.Add('SELECT MAX(Hours) AS [Max], MIN(Hours) AS [Min], AVG(Hours) AS [AVE]');
          sql.Add('FROM Professions');
          open;

          Max := fields[0];
          Min := fields[1];
          Ave := fields[2];
        end;
```

Is such a thing possible?
New to SQL, thanks anyway!

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Make sure your Sql allows for the possibility that more than one record has the Max and Minimum values.

Comment: @MartynA How would I do that?

Comment: See what @forpas says.  Personally, I would not have attempted to get all these values in a single query because of the problem of duplicates/multiplicates.

Comment: The general solution is to issue 3 queries: 1) Get the min and max values 2) Get the records that have the min value 2) Get the records that have the max value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found this solution. This would give the `Primary Key` or the record `ID`. It also allows for the possibility that there is more than one record with the `MAX()` or `MIN()` value.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Hours AS [Max] FROM Professions
    WHERE Hours = (SELECT MAX(Hours) FROM Professions)
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Here is proof using another database, though the same concept applies.
[image]

I actually wrote this code while working on a completely different problem.

Comment: @MartynA Would this be a suitable improvement?

Comment: Where is min and the average that you want in the results?

Comment: @forpas Thank you very much for your answer. But, my question simply wanted the values and their associated ID. The values need not all be in one query.

Comment: In your question you say: *Here I would like to get the ID (integer) field value of each of these values:...*

Comment: @forpas Yes, but they need not be all in one query. They could be in separate queries. I just needed to get the field value and assign it to local vars. To be more clear, these results are not displayed on a dbGrid via a query. They are added via adding columns.

Comment: Do you mean that you prefer to execute 3 separate queries to get all 3 values instead of just 1 query?

Comment: @forpas Yes, that was exactly what I meant. Pardon my lack of detail and expression. Though, If you can get multiple values for the `Max` or `Min` and have them all in as fields in 1 query, please post it.

Comment: I see that in your 1st comment you are asking if this way is *a suitable improvement*. May I ask how would you expect 3 queries, which is the least performant way, to be an *improvement*?

Comment: @forpas Well, yes. It makes room for the possibility for more than one record to have the maximum value. Although I admire your answer, to my specific situation and the title of this question, it think it is a suiteable answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT MAX(Hours) AS [Max],
       (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Professions ORDER BY Hours DESC) AS Max_ID, 
       MIN(Hours) AS [Min], 
       (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Professions ORDER BY Hours) AS Min_ID,
       AVG(Hours) AS [AVE]
FROM Professions
```

Each of the subqueries sorts the table either descending or ascending and picks the top row.

Comment: See my comment to the q.

Comment: @MartynA if there are 2 or more rows with the same max or min hours, the query will pick 1 the max_id and 1 as the min_id.